Download Electron zip file and how to locally install downloaded Electron offline on Ubuntu-22.04?
One of our productions is running Ubuntu-22.04, under request we need to install Electron, but it is not allowed to install via network connection. We have downloaded Electron zip file, but we have no idea how to install it locally. Please help.
Regards,
Harry

Are you referring to the electron npm package here? if so, then it looks like you can install from a local tar (not zip) archive. See for example npm install: Description

Thank you steeldriver for your reply. My question is how to install electron package locally. Right now I manually download npm and node package and install them. In my Ubuntu-22.04.3 system:
#npm -v
8.5.1
#node -v
v12.22.9
And I have downloaded electron: electron-v33.3.0-linux-x64.zip onto my system.
Question: is it possible to install this downloaded :electron-v33.3.0-linux-x64.zip into system locally?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
